# C# Remote connecting to Outlook mailbox in the cloud

Tags: outlook, office365

Is this possible to do using ASP.Net in C#?

We have exchange in the cloud and access using outlook 365.

If it is possible, how do you connect and can you access mail and mail attachment from a remote application?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Exchange Web Services API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx